# How to convert this.setState to setItemIdToSelectedMap?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I want to convert this function setState using hooks

```
this.setState(previousState => {
  const newItemIdToSelectedMap = {
    ...previousState.itemIdToSelectedMap,
    [itemId]: !previousState.itemIdToSelectedMap[itemId],
  };

  return {
    itemIdToSelectedMap: newItemIdToSelectedMap,
  };
});
```

Here is my initial state

```
 const [itemIdToSelectedMap, setItemIdToSelectedMap] = useState({});
```

I want to convert to something like this

```
const toggleItem = itemId => {
  setItemIdToSelectedMap(state => ({
    ...state,
    [itemId]: !state.itemIdToSelectedMap[itemId]
   }));
};
```

This is for the checkbox function. I want to make my specific checkbox checked but it's not working. Let me know what you think. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you dont need to use `itemIdToSelectedMap` again inside of your calback function that you are passing to your state setter, the state itself has the same value, your function should like below:

```
const toggleItem = itemId => {
  setItemIdToSelectedMap(state => ({
    ...state,
    [itemId]: !state[itemId]
   }));
};
```